# Wireless driver stops working after reboot

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

Decided to give Ubuntu a try after a couple of years away from Linux.

The Additional Drivers utility failed and so I ended up doing research online to find a fix.

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a Vista laptop (dual boot) that has a Broadcom 4312 wifi chip set and so it needed the b43 driver to work.

I followed the walk thru [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#Top) and everything seemed to be going fine.  Then when I rebooted it stopped working again so I had to open a terminal and do a sudo modprobe b43 to get it up and running again.

I followed the additional steps about the blacklisting in the Switching drivers section and tried to purge the bcmawl-kernal but my system doesn't have it so I got the message it couldn't find it.

What else is there for me to do in order to ensure the b43 gets loaded at boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do:

```
sudo su 

echo b43 >> /etc/modules 

exit
```

Now it should connect on boot.

Thanks